# Suggestions on how to track tag count for a particular object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm looking for suggestions on how to track the number of tags associated with a particular object in Rails. I'm using acts_as_taggable_on and it's working fine. What I would like to be able to do is search for all objects that have no tags, preferably through a scope i.e. Object.untagged.all

My first thought was to use an after_save callback to update an attribute called "taggings_count" in my model:

```
def update_taggings_count
  self.taggings_count = self.tag_list.size
  self.save
end
```

Unfortunately, this does the obvious thing of putting me in an infinite loop. I need to use an after_save callback because the tag_list is not updated until the main object is saved.

Would appreciate any suggestions as I'm on the verge of rolling my own tagging system.

Regards

Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing, but put the function in before_save, like so

```
scope :untagged, where("taggings_count = 0")
before_save :update_taggings_count

def update_taggings_count
  self.taggings_count = tag_list.size
end
```